# how to populate a store with a single json object in gxt3

Tags: json, extjs, gxt

I am using Sencha GXT3 app for a html interface. Data is retrieved in json format from a REST service. How exactly do I fill a store with a single object for reading and later manipulating and saving?

This is not about lists of objects, but really a specific single json map which I want to load into a store.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Stores you have basically two choices list or tree.  Right? [GXT 3 store api](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/Store.html)

You say it's not a list so did you see the src of their [json tree example](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3aasyncjsontree)

Personally for a single object, I use a list.  I mean it's a list of size 1. [json list example](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3ajsongrid)

Of those two examples,  [json tree example](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3aasyncjsontree) is easier to understand since it's not using a grid I think.  There are tree grid examples too but none I immediately see with json.

This is for version 3.  I see no reason why you'd want to start with 2 since 3 is much more similar to native gwt and you can mix 2 and three code (see their tutorial) until you get everything ported to the newer version.  Just saying ...